# CSV to XML conversion with XSLT 2.0 - Skip empty lines

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-2.0

**The background:**

I have a CSV file for input from an outside resource that I'm converting into XML. The XML is then used for more conversion work. 
The function I use to get the CSV to XML is from Andrew J. Welch: http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html.

```
<xsl:variable name="KortingOverzicht">
            <xsl:call-template name="Kortingoverzicht">
                <xsl:with-param name="pathToCSV" select="'discountoverview.csv'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:function name="fn:getTokens" as="xs:string+">
        <xsl:param name="str" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:analyze-string regex="(&quot;[^&quot;]*&quot;)+" select="$str">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:sequence
                    select="replace(., &quot;^&quot;&quot;|&quot;&quot;$|(&quot;&quot;)&quot;&quot;&quot;, &quot;$1&quot;)"
                />
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\s*,\s*')">
                    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template name="Kortingoverzicht">
            <xsl:param name="pathToCSV"/>

            <xsl:variable name="XMLkorting">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($pathToCSV)">
                        <xsl:variable name="csv" select="unparsed-text($pathToCSV)"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize($csv, '&#xa;')" as="xs:string+"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="elemNames" select="fn:getTokens($lines[1])" as="xs:string+"/>
                        <xsl:element name="Kortingoverzicht">
                            <xsl:for-each select="$lines[position() > 1]">
                                <Korting>
                                    <xsl:variable name="lineItems" select="fn:getTokens(.)"
                                        as="xs:string+"/>

                                    <xsl:for-each select="$elemNames">
                                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                                        <elem name="{.}">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$lineItems[$pos]"/>
                                        </elem>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </Korting>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>Bestand niet gevonden : </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$pathToCSV"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:element name="Kortingoverzicht">
                <xsl:for-each select="$XMLkorting/Kortingoverzicht/Korting">
                    <xsl:element name="Korting">
                        <xsl:element name="brandid">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(elem,';')"/>
                        </xsl:element>

                        <xsl:element name="brandname">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(elem,';'),';')"/>
                        </xsl:element>

                        <xsl:element name="discount">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(elem,';'),';')"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
```

**The problem:**

The CSV file is updated daily and is "as is". The file always contains an empty line at the end. The function doesn't like that and gives an error: *An empty sequence is not allowed as the result of function fn:getTokens()*

To solve that I always removed the empty line by hand. But now I want the whole XSLT to run automaticly and preferably without having to remove lines by hand.

**The question:**

Is there a way to alter the function or the call to it, so it skips any empty line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change `<xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize($csv, '&#xa;')" as="xs:string+"/>` to `<xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize($csv, '&#xa;')[normalize-space()]" as="xs:string+"/>` then empty lines are ignored.

Comment: That simple? I was trying/thinking all kinds of weird solutions... I'll give this a try, thanks.